# How to retrieve all the values of field in mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb

Here's an example of collection I have in Mongodb

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("54076c79f764e4ea431bf7f6"),
  "trends":[
  {
    "query":"%23Ces aroni",
    "name":"#Cesaroni",
    "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Cesaroni",
    "promoted_content":null
  },
  {
    "query":"%23MelihG%C3%B6kcekKKy%C4%B1De%C5%9Fi freEdiyor",
    "name":"#MelihGökcekKKyiDesifreEdiyor",
    "url":"http://twitter.co m/search?q=%23MelihG%C3%B6kcekKKy%C4%B1De%C5%9FifreEdiyor",
    "promoted_content":null
  },
  {
    "query":"%23EngvNor",
    "name":"#EngvNor",
    "url":"http://twitter. com/search?q=%23EngvNor",
    "promoted_content":null
  },
  "locations":[
  {
    "woeid":1,
    "name":"Worldwide"
  }
  ],
  "created_at":"2014-09-03T19:23:55Z",
  "as_of":"2014-09-03T19:31:05Z"
}
```

The collection is dumped to mongodb collection as it is retrieved from Twitter. Now, I want to add more data for other locations. Since this is the first time I'm using mongodb, I couldn't figure out how I can retrieve just the locations field.

Comment: what have you tried?  What results are you seeing? check [db.collection.find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: @dc5, I tried db.collection.find() which returns all the documents. I also tried db.collection.find({locations: "name"}) and bunch of other things which either returned nothing, or generated error.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) on the topic?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes, I did read it fairly quickly. I'm still confused about it. I'm used to relational database, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around to NoSQL approach. Here's another thing that I tried, db.trends.find({ locations: { $exists: true} }).pretty(); which just returned everything that contains locations. I just wanna know from all the data I have, how many different location names exist.

Comment: There are separate concepts of filtering (which docs to return) and projection (which fields to include from those docs), but that's actually pretty similar to SQL as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use projection with an empty or filtered query:

```
db.collectionName.find({},{locations:1})
```

Will retrieve something like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5407a0a9b7a33063850f5b09"),
"locations" : [
    {
        "woeid" : 1,
        "name" : "Worldwide"
    }
]
}
```